# What is the best way to pass provider specific configuration to different objects

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented-design

I am building a middleware integration that will pull orders from various 3rd party API's and push those orders into our system, as well as synchronize stock and send off shipments. I want to build this in such a way that I can add various retailers later on without having to modify the `Core` project.

I've built this into a few projects:

- Common (just common things such as WebClient, Serialization, IO etc)
- ERP (this is the ERP that we will be pushing this data into and this has all the models and services to push orders etc)
- Core (this will connect to a database to get a list of the various integrations that have been setup, load the providers DLL and then pull the orders etc)
- Providers.Retailer1 (these have a dependancy on the `ERP` project as it will return data such as orders in the models from the ERP)
- Providers.Retailer2
- Providers.Retailer3

Currently, my `Core` project has a project reference on the Providers. I want to get to a point whereby the Core doesn't have a hard reference to these providers - perhaps they are loaded dynamically at runtime by checking whether the class implements an interface. So, in theory, if we want to integrate with a new retailer, we would simply build out the implementation of getting orders/syncing stock etc. Does this sound like a sound approach? I was thinking of looking into MEF for this but not sure yet how that would look.

My problem is, is that `Retailer1` for example needs certain configurations and services such as `ApiKey`, `Username`, `Password` etc, where as `Retailer2` might require different configuration data. Currently,  The `Core` project is what will retrieve these details from the database. What is the best way to pass these to the `Providers`? Should I create a `Configuration` object that is basically a key/value pair of the configuration and program the interface to accept a `Configuration` object? And store these values in a key/value pair in a database table instead of columns as they currently are?

Currently I create the dependencies inside the `Core` project however this means the `Core` project is tightly coupled with `Retailer1` for example:

```
         TheIconic.Services.IApiService iconicApiService = new TheIconic.Services.TheIconicApiService(
            DependencyContainerProvider.Current.Container.Resolve<IWebClient>(),
            instance.IntegrationPartner.ApiUrl,
            instance.IntegrationPartner.ApiKey,
            instance.IntegrationPartner.Username,
            instance.IntegrationPartner.BasicAuthUsername,
            instance.IntegrationPartner.BasicAuthPassword
        );
```

Comment: If your ERP system is supposed to be agnostic to each provider, then added provider-specific configuration data sounds like you're allowing your ERP database to become polluted by all kinds of data which the ERP system seemingly doesn't need to know about.      Have you considered putting the DLL-specific configuration into `app.config` using `ConfigurationManager` instead?    ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232695/how-to-use-configurationmanager )

Comment: I don't want to store the configuration in files as I have a separate database to the erp the the "core" project talks to. It has a list of all the different partners, the class that implements their functions as well as any API configuration for that partner.

Comment: The Core is coupled to the Retailers  once their onfigurations are part of the data model. Aren't they? What's the benefit of storing the configurations in db? Do they change often?

Comment: The benefit of storing it in the DB is that my users can setup these integrations once the programming team has created the provider specific class for this retailer. We will have a front end where a user can "create a new integration" whereby they would put all the settings in (api key, username etc) and this is the configuration that I want to pass to the Retailer class.

Comment: `Currently, my Core project has a project reference on the Providers. I want to get to a point whereby the Core doesn't have a hard reference to these providers - perhaps they are loaded dynamically at runtime by checking whether the class implements an interface. So, in theory, if we want to integrate with a new retailer, we would simply build out the implementation of getting orders/syncing stock etc. Does this sound like a sound approach?`Looks like you are thinking in a modular architecture design. In that case, centralising all the configurations in the Core won't help you to decouple

Answer (score 1):

> Should I create a Configuration object that is basically a key/value pair of the configuration and program the interface to accept a Configuration object?

If a list of key/value pairs is all you need to configure a provider, then yes, this seems like a sound solution.  In fact it is the exact solution used by ODBC data providers (via the connection string, which is a list of key/value pairs stored in a text blob).

If you need something more complicated, you can still use a string but perhaps instead of tag/value pairs it could contain XML or JSON.

Comment: Great point... I never though of a connection string in that sense.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to pass these to the Providers?

Why don't you consider DI injection? Create any number of specific data factories for providers, that are using `Core` classes to build data inside and then pass those factories into `Providers`' constructors via Dependency Injection library such as NInject. That way your providers are isolated from the core.

Comment: So in my core, it is still aware of the different configuration options that are available to each provider? Wouldn't this create a circular reference between the `Core` and the `Providers` because the providers need to receive the factory?

Comment: @Lock No, core doesn't know that. And factory doesn't either. Factories just prepare data in some format and variety using your core services. Neither factories nor core know where factories are going to be injected with. And you just inject a factory into a provider.